# Write Spark worker logs to stdout/stderr

Tags: apache-spark, logging, cluster-computing, stdout, stderr

Hi I am trying to redirect Spark workers logs to stdout/stderr.

I have added custom log4j.properties file that looks like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, stdout, stderr
# configure stdout
log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold = TRACE
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1.levelMin = TRACE
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1.levelMax = INFO
log4j.appender.stdout.Target = System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %p %c: %m%n
# configure stderr
log4j.appender.stderr = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.Threshold = WARN
log4j.appender.stderr.Target = System.err
log4j.appender.stderr.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %p %c: %m%n
# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader = ERROR
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=WARN
log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty.server=WARN
```

Still logs are not redirected to stdout/stderr but to stdout and stderr files on the disk.

Anyone knows how can I make it work?

EDIT: reading from [this blog post](http://www.russellspitzer.com/2018/11/27/SparkOutput/) it seems like it is just the way it works